# adjust EditTexts and buttons with different screen sizes

Tags: android, xml

How can I adjust EditTexts and Buttons to fit any screen size for android ? I'm trying to put some transparent EditTexts and Buttons in certain positions to fit my background image, but when I change screen size every thing changes. Here are my background image and my XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/login_page"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10sp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Login"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:padding="8sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="8sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:minHeight="40sp"
        android:minWidth="500sp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#08b0ef" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I tried other units like dp and dpi and dip but no one is giving the expected result.

Comment: You should use **dp** for Views, not **sp**. **sp** is for text sizes only.

Comment: as I said in my question I've already tried it.

Comment: Mine isn't a solution. Just a tip to `use the proper units`.

Comment: Because I'm not sure to understand what `adjust EditTexts and Buttons to fit any screen size` means.

Comment: I mean that I want the EditTexts to stay up to the dark-blue areas and the button to stay up to the white area regardless to the device's resulotion.

Comment: So, I guess you need a RelativeLayout. The LinearLayout is useless.

Comment: Also since Android screen are different sizes your background image might be squashed or stretched. You might want to put the image in an image view and look into the scaling of this. If you want the buttons to match exactly on top of the boxes why don't you make them that background. That will save you trying to fiddle with pixels.

Comment: try to make same layout in 'layout-large' folder under res directory. This is used for large screen layouts.(you need to create this folder)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "android:layout_weight" ?
I think what your talking about to set your Layout objects in a certain position relative to the background and once set, stay fixed proportionally so when the background stretches our contracts so do the buttons so they stay in the same position over the background?

If so (I could be way off),
setting the layout_weight attribute inside of each child object of the LinearLayout can let you position everything relative to the screen size so it automatically changes with each screen size. It will take a little trial and error to get the right percentages but should work.

Also consider creating multiple xml layout definitions for the major screen sizes so the OS automatically calls the one it needs for a particular screen with a resource qualifier, that way you know it will display in the right position. For example a xml called activity_main in R.layout is inflated by default but if you also create a activity_main in R.layout-land, this XML will only be inflated if the screen is in landscape mode. So you can set the sizes of your editText and Buttons for multiple screen size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create only one file for all layout and trying to make your screen universal, you should try Linearlayout with weight property.

Instead of using sp or px, you should use pd for margin, padding or any other properties in your layout. dp will render differently as per screen resolution.